# Excel VBA - Iterate all rows and highlight all rows within the same specific characters

Tags: vba, excel, loops, iteration

I have an excel file that looks something like this (A's and Z's replaced w/ actual data):

```
1    ===
2    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
3    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
4    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
5    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
6    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
7    ===
8    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
9    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
10    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
11    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
12    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
13    ===
14    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
15    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
16    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
17    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
18    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
19    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
20    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
21    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
22    ===
23    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
24    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
25    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
26    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
27    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
28    ===
29    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
30    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
31    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
32    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
33    ===
34    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
35    ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

I need to be able to iterate through all n lines and highlight all lines that are contained within the "===" delimiter. This means I need to be able to highlight the following lines: 1-7, 13-22, and 28-33. (i.e. each "odd" instance of a delimiter is the start and each "even" instance is the end).

I am thinking of setting a flag variable to be turned on when encountering the first delimter then turning it off again on the next, and turning on again, and so forth but I am not able to correctly toggle it.

Can anyone share some code snippet be able to highlight the necessary lines?

Comment: Show us what have you tried till now...

Comment: @Maciej Los - Unfortunately I have already deleted my trial code since this is my first time with VBA and I got upset with my progress.

Comment: You should consider using conditional formatting for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code. Observe that you can specify the column to work on and the first row to search for delimiters in, in case you have column captions.

```
Sub GroupData()
    ' 07 Nov 2017

    Const SearchColumn As String = "B"          ' change as appropriate
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1                  ' change as appropriate

    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last row
    Dim Rmark As Long
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim Rstart As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SearchColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        Rmark = FindRow(Range(Cells(FirstRow, SearchColumn), Cells(Rl, SearchColumn)))
        Do While Rmark
            Counter = Counter + 1
            If Counter Mod 2 Then
                Rstart = Rmark + 1
            Else
                .Range(.Cells(Rstart, SearchColumn), _
                       .Cells(Rmark - 1, SearchColumn)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
            Rmark = FindRow(Range(Cells(Rmark + 1, SearchColumn), Cells(Rl, SearchColumn)))
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

Function FindRow(Rng As Range) As Long
    ' 06 Nov 2017
    ' return 0 if not found

    Dim Fnd As Range

    With Rng
        Set Fnd = .Find(What:="===", _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        MatchByte:=False)
    End With
    If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then FindRow = Fnd.Row
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to achieve that. One of them is:

```
Option Explicit 'force variable declaring

Sub MarkSomeData()
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim iStart As Integer, iEnd As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet

'working sheet
Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

iCounter = 1
Do While wsh.Range("A" & iCounter) <> ""
    If wsh.Range("A" & iCounter) = "===" Then
        If iStart = 0 Then iStart = iCounter
        If iEnd <= iStart Then iEnd = iCounter
        If iEnd > iStart Then
            wsh.Range("A" & iStart & ":A" & iEnd).Font.Color = vbRed
            iStart = 0
            iEnd = 0
        End If
    End If
    iCounter = iCounter + 1
Loop

Set wsh = Nothing

End Sub
```

Feel free to change the code to your needs.

Good luck!